# Can't Create Function to Create Unique Array

Tags: c, arrays, function

Purpose of Code:
I am trying to create a code that from user input, will generate an array of 'size (no more than 7)' length from user input, using function 'uniqueRand' it will then generate random numbers from 1-9, then use function 'found' to check if the number is already present in the array, then make a new number if it is.

Problem:
Compiling, I get a warning that variable 'value' is not used, but I declare it in the function, then use it in the for loop underneath it

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <time.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int uniqueRand (int a[], int size);

int found (int a[], int size, int value);

int main (){
int size, guesses;
printf ("Number of digits?: ");
scanf ("%d", &size);
int a[size];
printf ("\nNumber of guesses?: \n"); 
scanf ("%d", &guesses);  
int uniqueRand (int a[],int size);  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf ("%d",a[i]);
            //Print Answer Code  
    }      
}
int uniqueRand (int a[], int size){
      //Generate Random Array Function
int value;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (i == 0){
            a[0] = rand () % 8 + 1;
        }  
        else{
            while (1){
                a[i] = rand () % 8 + 1;
                value = a[i]; //value to check for     
                int found (int a[],int size,int value);//Check if value is in a[], if true then redo
            }
        }
    }
return 1;
}

int found (int a[], int size, int value){   
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){    
        if (a[i] == value){ //checks if it is in a[i]  
            break;
            return 1;
        }
    //if it is return 1 and break, because need a new number          
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you've got an infinite loop with your `while(1)`.  And you are giving the prototype of the `found` function within that loop, not calling that function.

Comment: What do you think that this line does? `int found (int a[],int size,int value);//Check if value is in a[], if true then redo` It has the syntax of a prototype declaratin but your comment seems to indicate that you believe it to be a call to the function. This means that `value` gets written, but never read.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I understand the calling issue, and have resolved it with no warning, but I am stuck in that infinite loop when running. By introducing while(1), I am then calling found(a, size, value), which returns 1 if the value is already present in a, or 0 if not present. Why would it not exit?

Comment: Please create a new answer on your new problem. Meanwhile please let me know how I can make my answer for this question (as asked) be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int found (int a[],int size,int value);//Check if value is in a[], if true then redo
```

has the syntax of a prototype declaration, but your comment seems to indicate that you believe it to be a call to the function. It is not. Apart from the unusual declaration of a prototype inside a function (I recommend not to...) this means that value gets written, but never read.

I would have to guess, but what you intend to do probably requires the calling syntax for a function, which would be something like the following (note the absence of types):

```
found(a, size, value);
```

I am not saying that it functionally achieves yoru goal, but the syntax means that now `value` is in fact used for something, instead of being written and otherwise ignored.

Your function has a return value and you probably will want to use it (with the line above the return value gets ignored...). But that is not in scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have another run-time error, in what seems the found(a,size, value) function. If the found finds the value, it returns i, if it does not find anything it returns -1, and the while(1){ should break, but it does not and the code runs forever.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <time.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int uniqueRand (int a[], int size);

int found (int a[], int size, int value);

int main (){

int size, guesses;

printf ("Number of digits?: ");

scanf ("%d", &size);

int a[size];
printf ("\nNumber of guesses?: \n");

scanf ("%d", &guesses);

uniqueRand (a,size);
//Generate Random Array Callout

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

        printf ("%d",a[i]);
//Print Answer Code  
    }   

}

int uniqueRand (int a[], int size){
//Generate Random Array Function
    int value;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        if (i == 0){    
            a[0] = rand () % 8 + 1; 
        }         
        else
        {
            while (1){
                a[i] = rand () % 8 + 1;
                value = a[i]; //value to check for     
                found (a,size,value);
             //Checks to see if value is in a[] already, if true then redo 
                    if (found(a,size,value) == -1) 
                    //If -1 return, number is unique, break
                        break;
            }

        }

    }
return a[size];

}

int found (int a[], int size, int value){

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

        if (a[i] == value) //checks if value is in a[i]  
            return i; //if yes, returns positive number
    }                       
    return -1; //return -1 if unique        
}
```